# I can't play the camera video yet, please tell me where I'm wrong

Tags: flutter, http, camera, rtsp

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp9999());

class MyApp9999 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: CameraScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class CameraScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CameraScreenState createState() => _CameraScreenState();
}

class _CameraScreenState extends State<CameraScreen> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;
  String cameraAddress = 'kbplawyer.cameraddns.net';
  String port = '8010';
  String username = 'admin';
  String password = '1qazxsw2';
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    String encodedUsername = Uri.encodeComponent(username);
    String encodedPassword = Uri.encodeComponent(password);
    String videoUrl =
        'http://$encodedUsername:$encodedPassword@$cameraAddress:$port/stream';
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoUrl);
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(
      uri,
      videoPlayerOptions: VideoPlayerOptions(mixWithOthers: true),
    );
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _controller.initialize().then((_) {
      setState(() {});
      _controller.play();
    });
  }
```

I use flutter to stream a camera live using http method, but it doesn't work
I can't play the camera video yet, please tell me where I'm wrong,
Currently videos using http are not playing.

Comment: Can you give a bit more details about what is the actual problem?
Do you have error logs? It would help if you shared your build method as well. thx!

Comment: On the first try, I receive the following error from the player
Error: Source error
Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted
Cleartext HTTP traffic to kbplawyer.cameraddns.net not permitted

Is your server set up correctly?

Comment: Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$CleartextNotPermittedException: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/issues/cleartext-not-permitted

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error, null, null)
E/flutter (24839):

Comment: check out https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/7242